# Get last result of query and set it to variable

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the last (most recent) record from a query and set it to the value of a declared variable, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
DECLARE @PriceID int
SELECT TOP 1 log_id = @PriceID
  FROM price_logs
 WHERE part_id = 45
 ORDER BY log_id DESC
```

In this instance, the `part_id` value doesn't matter, it just need to be a value that exists within the database.  When I run this code I am getting a blank value for `@PriceID`, yet when I check the values in the `price_logs` table, there is a data row to be collected.  So what is it I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the variable and column name so you are setting the value to the variable, not the other way around. How you have it written, you are setting the column name `log_id` to the value of `@PriceID` which is currently `NULL` since you only declared it.

```
DECLARE @PriceID int
SELECT TOP 1 @PriceID = log_id
  FROM price_logs
 WHERE part_id = 45
 ORDER BY log_id DESC
```

Comment: *facepalm*  I didn't think I could do that because I had been trying to write it as `SELECT @PriceID = TOP 1 log_id` and was getting an error.  Now I know where the error was >_>